# mysql group sum same table

Tags: mysql, database, select, sum

I have the following table:

| id | name | type | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | orange | 2345 |
| 2 | john | yellow | 5 |
| 3 | john | black | 5454540 |
| 4 | jack | orange | 1123 |
| 5 | jack | yellow | 1000 |
| 6 | jack | black | 86943 |
| 7 | jane | orange | 9876 |
| 8 | jane | yellow | 10000 |
| 9 | jane | black | 102233 |

**comment;**

```
id : inte
name :   same name save more times to more rows, 
score: it is int data
type : it has string data black,white,yellow,purple,orange
```

I'm using the following queries to calculate two score totals

```
SELECT name,sum(score) as `first` 
FROM salary 
WHERE type = 'orange' 

SELECT name,sum(score) as `second` 
FROM salary 
WHERE type in ('black','yellow')
```

i want see result that ( all names must be group, single name.)

| name | FirstScore | SecondScore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 2345 | 5454545 |
| jack | 1123 | 87943 |
| jane | 9876 | 112233 |

Comment: What did you do to get what you want? (You should to more than just ask, i.e. you should explain where your problem is)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't *describe* your schema - just show it to us in the form of CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements (sample values).  Also, A) show us what you've tried and B) Using the sample values, post an example of the expected results.  (All of this as text, *not* screen shots)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Updated the question to show an example of how to post an [mre]. Also, fixed the sql as an alias isn't valid in the WHERE clause, i.e. `WHERE type in ('black','yellow') as second;` is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional SUM() to aggregate the values based on `type`:

```
 SELECT name
        , SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('orange') THEN score END ) AS FirstScore
        , SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('yellow','black') THEN score END ) AS SecondScore
 FROM   salary
 GROUP BY Name
```

Results:

| name | FirstScore | SecondScore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 2345 | 5454545 |
| jack | 1123 | 87943 |
| jane | 9876 | 112233 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99d30394e58d2be76c48e9a340c497f2)*

Comment: SELECT name
        , SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('orange') THEN score END ) AS FirstScore
        , SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('yellow','black') THEN score END ) AS SecondScore
 FROM   salary where type in('Orange','yellow','black')/* if there is brown , no need in list*/
 GROUP BY Name

thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (but this is untested):

```
SELECT 
   salary.name,
   first.score as "first_score",
   second.score as "second_score"
FROM salary
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name,sum(score) as score
           FROM salary 
           WHERE type = 'orange'
          ) as first  ON first.name = salary.name
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name,sum(score)  as score
           FROM salary 
           WHERE type in ('black','yellow')
          ) as second ON second.name = salary.name
```